# Exclude leading NULL values from table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

To give some context, I am using time series data (one column) and I want to study gaps in the data, represented by NULL values in the data set. Although I expect some leading NULL values that I am not interested in including in my final data set. However the number of leading NULL values will vary between data sets.

I would like to exclude the top x number of rows of my data set where the value of a particular column is NULL, without excluding NULL values that appear lower in the same column.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT: I also know that my first record in the value column is always 1, if that helps.

Comment: How do you define "leading"? You'd need to order by something - rows inherently do not have an order in the database.

Comment: Please show your query that incorrectly excludes `NULL`s inside the gaps. It's much easier to correct an error than to guess your table structure and then suggest a fix.

Comment: @Bridge I have a second column showing row_number that is how I am sorting the records.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight the query is simply SELECT row_number,value FROM <table> WHERE value is not NULL. However this removes all of the nulls in column<value>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, for SQL Server 2008, I can't think of anything cleaner than:

```
SELECT row_number,value FROM <table> t1
WHERE value is not NULL OR
     EXISTS (select * FROM <table> t2
             where t2.value is not null and
             t2.row_number < t1.row_number)
```

---

Just as an aside, for SQL Server 2012, you could use `MAX()` with an appropriate [`OVER()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) clause such that it considers all previous rows. If that `MAX()` returns `NULL` then all preceding rows are known to be `NULL`, and that's what I'd recommend if/when you upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You could find the first non-null item for each data set and then just query everything after that:

```
WITH FirstItem AS
(
   SELECT 
       DataSetID,
       MIN(row_number) row_number
   FROM Data
   WHERE value IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY DataSetID
)
SELECT d.* FROM Data d
INNER JOIN FirstItem fi
  ON d.DataSetID = fi.DataSetid
  AND d.row_number >= fi.row_number
```